# Remembering a value

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a nodejs application deployed to heroku. This application has a counter variable.

Each time a certain event occurs, this counter variable is incremented.

Now, I don't want to lose the value of this counter. That is, in the scenario that the nodejs app is restarted, I want that the value of this counter be set to what it was before restarting.

In other words, I need to "remember" a value that will be changed inside the nodejs app deployed to heroku.

Is there any add-on or is it possible to set environment variables or something on those lines?

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the value somewhere. You can save it to a file or to a database. Given that your app doesn't sound super complicated, a file probably makes the most sense. Use the [fs module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) found in the node core.

```
var fs = require('fs');

// Save counter value to file.
function saveCount(count) {
    fs.writeFileSync('counter.dat', count);
}

// Retrieve counter value from file.
function getCount() {
    return parseInt(fs.readFileSync('counter.dat'));
}
```

If you want to go with a simple name/value database then have a look at [redis](http://redis.io/) and their [node client](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis).

Answer (score 0):

All you need is some kind of database. For example mongodb , mysql and so on. You will be able  to store event number in it. If you don't want to use database, just use simple text file.